# swift5 how to only display limited photo library after user has granted limited access to select some photos

Tags: swift, photokit

In WWDC2020, new PHPickerViewController and new PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(limited) were introduced. But I got below issue:

1. when user tapped a button to show the apple's multiple images picker and display the requestAuthorization as code:

   ```
    let requiredAccessLevel: PHAccessLevel = .readWrite
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: requiredAccessLevel) { (authorizationStatus) in
          switch authorizationStatus {
          case .authorized:
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.presentImagePicker()
               }
          case .limited:
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.presentImagePicker()
               }
          default:
              break
          }
   }
   ```
2. self.presentImagePicker() functions:

   ```
    func presentImagePicker() {
    var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
    configuration.filter = .images
    configuration.selectionLimit = self.imageCountMax - self.images.count
    let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
    picker.delegate = self

    let accessLevel: PHAccessLevel = .readWrite
    let authorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: accessLevel)

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.present(picker, animated: true)
        }
    case .limited:
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Here I don't know how to display only limited photo library to users (after user has selected some photos through the limited access)
        }
    default:
        break
    }
   ```

   }

my issue: please see code 2, case .limited: DispatchQueue.main.async { }, I think I should put the limited photo library in this block, but I don't know how to display only limited photo library to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: self)` method into `.limited`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
         // Here I don't know how to display only limited photo library to users (after user has selected some photos through the limited access)
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: self)
     }
```

and after that you have to use the delegate method for get the updated images.

```
func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        self.allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
    }
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you please explain how you declared allPhotos?

Comment: @Quailcreek : var allPhotos: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!

Comment: What's the delegate you are implementing?